# integer expression expected in Fedora/UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, sh, fedora

I've been trying to figure a script for printing the Fibonacci Sequence but ran along some roadblocks.

```
1  #!/bin/sh
2  echo "Program to Find Fibonacci Series"
3  echo "How many number of terms to be generated ?"
4  read
5  n=$REPLY
6  echo "Fibonacci Series up to $n terms :"
7  x=0
8  y=1
9  i=2
10  echo "$x"
11  echo "$y"
12  while [ $i -lt $n ] 
13  do
14    i=`expr $i+1`
15    z=`expr $y+$x`
16    echo "$z"
17    x=$y
18    y=$z
19  done
20
21  exit 0
```

Specifically on line 12-13, where it keeps printing

```
integer expression expected
```

in the terminal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Run your script through shellcheck.

Comment: With bash your script works fine if you fix `expr $i+1` and `expr $y+$x`.

Comment: Don't use `expr` at all. `i=$((i + 1))` and `z=$((y + x))` will work in any POSIX-compliant shell, including `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `POSIX`manual for read. see [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html)

```
NAME

    read - read from standard input into shell variables

SYNOPSIS

    read [-r] var...

DESCRIPTION
```

You should be using

```
read -r n
```

Well `-r` is optional.

---

This solution is using `$(())` for the math/arithmetic context.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Program to Find Fibonacci Series"
read -rp "How many number of terms to be generated ? " n

 case $n in
  *[!0-9]*) printf 'You entered %s which is not an int, please try again shall we?\n' "$n"  >&2
     exit 1;;
     '') printf "Nothing was given, please try again..."
     exit 1;;
esac

echo "Fibonacci Series up to $n terms :"

x=0 y=1 i=2

printf '%s\n' "$x" "$y"
while [ $i -lt $n ]; do
  i=$((i+1))
  z=$((y+x))
  echo "$z"
  x=$y
  y=$z
done
```

- I have added case statement to validate the user input if it is indeed an int.
- I did not change your whole code I just change/fix what was giving the error.
- Add `-r` and `-p` is not POSIX but the `-r` is.
- Use `read n` if `-p` is not working for you and use the echo to output some messages to stdout like what you did.